# Bilinear form on the set of continuous functions with compact domain

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $K_1, K_2$ be a compact set, $C(K_i)$ be the set of continuous functions on $K_i$, and $B(C(K_1)\times C(K_2))$ be the set of bounded bilinear form on $C(K_1)\times C(K_2)$.

It is well-known that the set of linear functionals on $C(K)$ can be characterized by a regular Borel measure. I wonder the similar thing holds for $B(C(K_1)\times C(K_2))$.

Let $B\in B(C(K_1)\times C(K_2))$, can I conclude that there is a typical type of measure $\mu$ on $K_1\times K_2$ such that $B(f,g)=\int_{K_1\times K_2}f(x)g(y)d\mu$?
I guess it isn't true but I can't find a counter example. Thanks for help!